# MySQL needed to join tables of Grocery Stores, UPC Codes, and Prices

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm tracking grocery prices for a chain of stores, and I'm having trouble with the MySQL statement.

My three tables are set up like follows:

1. upccode_table, with two fields: upc_code, item_name
2. storelist_table, with three fields: store_code, store_name, store_address
3. price_table, with four fields: upc_code, store_code, price_amount, price_date

I need my price_table to show/return ALL possible combinations!!  This includes all UPC Codes, and ALL store names, and ALL price_amounts, EVEN IF NULL.

My data entry will replace the NULL values with real ones.

My first stab at this, but my syntax is not correct.

```
select itemlist.upccode as Code, storetable.storecode as Number   
from code itemlist  
inner join Pricelist p on itemlist.upccode = pricelist.upccode  
inner join storenumber s on storetable.storenumber = pricelist.storenumber  
order by itemlist.upccode
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN to get codes even if they are missing price lists or stores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your INNER join to LEFT OUTER join:

```
select itemlist.upccode as Code, storetable.storecode as Number
from code itemlist
LEFT OUTER join Pricelist p on itemlist.upccode = pricelist.upccode
LEFT OUTER join storenumber s on storetable.storenumber = pricelist.storenumber
order by itemlist.upccode
```

Comment: AJ, Thanks for the suggestion.

When I run that code, I get an error that says "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'grocery.code' doesn't exist' in /h..."

Comment: @Paul - all I did was copy your code and replace `INNER` with `LEFT OUTER`.  I don't see `grocery` table listed in your query (or my revision of it).  It sounds like a framework error that must have existed before?

Comment: AJ...you're correct...I had a typo....my "storenumber" should have been "storecode".   Thank you so much

Comment: @Paul - no problem.  Glad I could be of help.

Comment: AJ, what is the meaning of the small "p" after "Pricelist" and the small "s" after "storenumber"?

I translated this code from an example I found on the 'net.  If the small letters don't mean anything to you, they might have referred to the sample I copied from

Comment: @Paul - they are called aliases.  Basically you use them to rename your table in the scope of your query to a shorter (different) name.  Then, you can refer to that table by its alias instead of its full (proper) name.  You can read more about aliases here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html